# Use induction to prove that: $f^{(n)}(x) = xf^{(n−1)}(x) + (n − 1)f^{(n−2)}(x),n>2$

Tags: induction

Let $f$ be such that $f'(x)=xf(x)$
Use induction to proove that:

$f^{(n)}(x) = xf^{(n−1)}(x) + (n − 1)f^{(n−2)}(x)$

holds for all $n \geq 2$.

How do I even prove that this holds for n=2?
I've tried taking the second derivative and plugging in n = 2, but what I get makes no sense.
I'm then asked to relate this result with maclaurin series and a differential eq. Have made some progress on this, but i cannot figure out how to do the induction step.

Comment: For $n=2$, the statement to be proven is:  $f''(x) = x f'(x) + f(x)$.  When you computed the second derivative, is that what you got?

Comment: Differentiate both sides of $f'(x) = xf(x)$ to prove for $n=2$?

Comment: What do you get when you apply the product rule to the piece(s) on the right, either in the original equation or the inductive one you're trying to prove?

Comment: A "proof" needs two letters "o" ; "proving" needs only one...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments for $n=2$ you just need to differentiate and you get $f^{(2)}(x) = f(x) + x f'(x) = x f^{(2-1)}(x) + (2-1) f^{(2-2)}(x)$ which is what you wanted.

For the induction step differentiate the formula $f^{(n)}(x) = xf^{(n−1)}(x) + (n − 1)f^{(n−2)}(x)$:
$$f^{(n+1)}(x) = f^{(n−1)}(x) + xf^{(n)}(x) + (n − 1)f^{(n−1)}(x)= xf^{(n)}(x) + (n)f^{(n−1)}(x)$$
and we are done.

Answer (score 2):

According to your assumption if $f'(x)=xf(x)$ then, firstly $f(x)=0$ is one solution. And,
$$f'(x)=xf(x) \implies \frac{f'}{f}=x$$
Note that $\frac{f'}{f}$ is the logarithmic derivative of $f$.
So,
$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln f=x$$
Integration on both sides,
$$\ln f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}$$
$$f(x)=e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$$
Now I believe you can proceed by yourself.